# WPF/EF/SQLite The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite

I have been pulling my hair for many hours on this. I'm new to C# et .NET so I apologize if this is something trivial.

I'm trying to use WPF with Entity framework + SQLite.

I have managed to connect to the SQLite database by manually doing:

```
var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountHelper.Properties.Settings.AccountHelperConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
executeReader();
```

I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

I really have no clue on how to fix this. It is really frustrating!

EDIT: I answered this with a tutorial to configure everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my direct question above, the issue was that TextContext didn't know about the connection string. So if you give the same name to your Context as your string value, it will remove this error message.

That said, the configuration was completely wrong. I managed to make it working. Because I struggle a lot, I will share what I did to have it working.

***Step to step guide to configure it***

Configuration of a WPF project to work with Entity Framework (ADO.NET) and SQLite

Configuring this can be really tricky, even more if you have tried other methods before. So I advise to completely uninstall any SQLite software you might have installed.

1) Depending on your visual studio version, install sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.93.0.exe or equivalent. You can find it on [sqlite.org](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Few points:

- I know for a fact that the 1.0.98.0 and 1.0.99.0 won't work with visual studio 2012. It works but you get an issue when creating your ADO.NET item in the project.
- On this webpage, you can't find the old version, you will have to manually modify the URL to get the version you want.
- On this webpage, make sure to select a version that has "This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013. " visual studio 2013 or not.
- Install the exe and make sure to tick the designer related component during the install.

2) Create a new WPF project. Again, if you use a project you already modified, you might have some config issues. You better start a new project, do the config and once you know how to do it, port it to your project.

3) Install the Entity framework via the nugget manager.

4) Add manually (NOT WITH THE NUGGET MANAGER !!!) the following references that you can find in Assemblies -> Extension:

- System.Data.SQLite Core
- System.Data.SQLite Designer
- System.Data.SQLite for Entity Framework
- System.Data.SQLite for LINQ

5) Add a new item to this project -> Data -> ADO.NET blabla. Name it as you wish and create. You will need to create a connection for it. This is where if you don't have a compatible SQLite version, you won't be able to create a SQLite connection.

6) Then make sure your App.config look like the following, you might need to change the provider:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description="Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AccountHelperEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AccountHelperModel.csdl|res://*/AccountHelperModel.ssdl|res://*/AccountHelperModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;W:\visual studio projects\AccountHelper\AccountHelper\Data\AccountHelper.sqlite3&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

7) You are good to go.

You can see the project source code on [this link](https://bitbucket.org/dyesdyes9/accounthelper/overview). Check the code from the First commit, it contains everything you need. The other commits are project specific.